# Large Rectangular Touch Sensor

Tags: pcb-design, button, touch-panel

I'm looking to make a timer for Rubik's Cube solving, which looks like this:

[image: SpeedStacks Timer]

My design just has some added features and a different output type.

However, I'm not sure how best to replicate the hand sensors. They're just binary, "hand on"/"hand off". The pressure required to trigger the sensor should not be very high.

I have a couple of ideas, but I can't imagine that the actual product does any of these. Which one of these is the best, or is there a better way?

1. Each hand sensor is just a physical array of, say, 10 small pushbuttons laid out in a horizontal line. Each one is wired in parallel between VCC and signal so that if any are pushed, the signal is pulled high. I would have a plastic sheet over the top of the pushbuttons so that pressing anywhere (or everywhere) on the sheet will trigger multiple pushbuttons.
2. Have a strip of conductive metal along the bottom of the hand sensor area, and then another strip on top. Separate the two by some sort of spring, and then when pressed the two will contact. There would also be some sort of plastic sheet over the top just to make it look better.
3. Use capacitive touch sensing. (I'm not sure how cheap this is though, or if it works through a thin plastic sheet.)

The signals (one for each hand) just need to be read by some microprocessor -- I haven't decided on one yet, but probably some simple ATMega.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or do number 4. Definitely the cheapest and simplest one. Make use of the resistance of your body. The average human got about 5MΩ resistance in their skin. Passing through a small current is absolutely okay. You're just sensing, not electrocuting.

Use a Darlington transistor (make one with two **BJT** transistors). As you can see, the \$V_{low}\$ is about 0.5V, in reality it will be closer to 0.7V. If that is too high for your µC(microController) to understand that it is a low, then add another transistor at the output which will work as a buffer.

[image: human touch sensor darlington]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0At%20624%20384%20656%20384%200%201%200.413069621710223%200.443818541542343%20100%0At%20656%20400%20688%20400%200%201%20-0.030748919832120025%200.5552464845416171%20100%0Aw%20656%20368%20688%20368%200%0Aw%20688%20368%20688%20384%200%0Ag%20688%20416%20688%20432%200%0Ar%20464%20288%20464%20384%200%205000000%0Ar%20688%20288%20688%20368%200%2010000%0Aw%20528%20288%20688%20288%200%0AR%20688%20288%20688%20256%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20768%20368%20800%20368%202%0AM%20800%20368%20832%20368%200%202.5%0Aw%20768%20368%20688%20368%200%0Aw%20624%20384%20528%20384%200%0Aw%20528%20384%20528%20352%200%0Aw%20528%20288%20528%20320%200%0Aw%20528%20288%20528%20256%200%0Aw%20528%20384%20528%20416%200%0Ax%20536%20274%20637%20277%204%2016%20copper%5Csplate%0Ax%20535%20406%20636%20409%204%2016%20copper%5Csplate%0Ax%20375%20345%20445%20348%204%2024%20finger%0As%20464%20384%20528%20384%200%200%20false%0As%20464%20288%20528%20288%200%200%20false%0A) if you want to interact with the schematic.

---

If the µC can't register that 0.7V is a low input. Then this schematic will guarantee that it will work.

[image: human touch sensor darlington + inverter]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0At%20624%20384%20656%20384%200%201%200.4132968475598918%200.44091554281110235%20100%0At%20656%20400%20688%20400%200%201%20-0.027618695251210523%200.5517660817055926%20100%0Aw%20656%20368%20688%20368%200%0Aw%20688%20368%20688%20384%200%0Ag%20688%20416%20688%20432%200%0Ar%20464%20288%20464%20384%200%205000000%0Aw%20528%20288%20768%20288%200%0AR%20768%20288%20768%20256%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20848%20384%20880%20384%202%0AM%20880%20384%20912%20384%200%202.5%0Aw%20624%20384%20528%20384%200%0Aw%20528%20384%20528%20352%200%0Aw%20528%20288%20528%20320%200%0Aw%20528%20288%20528%20256%200%0Aw%20528%20384%20528%20416%200%0Ax%20536%20274%20637%20277%204%2016%20copper%5Csplate%0Ax%20535%20406%20636%20409%204%2016%20copper%5Csplate%0Ax%20375%20345%20445%20348%204%2024%20finger%0As%20464%20384%20528%20384%200%200%20false%0As%20464%20288%20528%20288%200%200%20false%0Ag%20768%20416%20768%20432%200%0Ar%20768%20384%20768%20416%200%2010000%0Aw%20848%20384%20768%20384%200%0At%20736%20368%20768%20368%200%20-1%20-0.5682207071312355%20-0.5813074394693922%20100%0Aw%20768%20288%20768%20352%200%0Ar%20688%20368%20736%20368%200%2010000%0A) if you want to interact with the schematic.

Comment: Thank you! Would the two copper plates both be on the top in this case, but with one on the left half and one on the right half of each hand sensor? I'm trying to get an idea of the physical layout.

Comment: Just two conducting _things_ separated, and the only thing that connects them is your finger. Yes, they would be on the top, and to make sure that the user presses both right and left, they will have to complete the circuit with both of their hands. Anti cheating system.

Comment: Would there be a low enough resistance from one hand of the user, through the arm, down the other arm, and to the other hand, to make it viable to just check for continuity between the left and right hand sensors? Or do I still need to do one of these sensors per hand?

Comment: Here's a fun thing, the resistance from your right hand to the left hand is almost the exact same as from your right hand to another part of your right hand. If you don't believe me, grab a multimeter and set it to the mega ohm range and start measuring your skin. I'm measuring right now to make sure I'm not lying. 240kOhm from right hand to left hand with alligator clips. 100kOhm from thumb to same thumb. -- Meh... as long as it's lower than 10Mohm you should be alright. 360kOhm on other thumb

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! This looks very promising.

Comment: @Jashaszun Whatever you do, don't place any resistor between the copper plate that goes to the Darlington transistor(100MΩ=big). If you do then it will act like a high impedance input, and just like your hair flows up when you're charged, the same thing will happen to the copper plate end, charges might build up from capacitive effects (like you being charged and moving your hand towards the plate). If there's no resistor then all the charges will bleed slowly through the transistor without falsely activating it.  W/ a large impedance input it will react to the mains electricity in the walls.

Comment: I wasn't planning on adding a resistor for either plate. Should I do it for the one without the Darlington? Or should I just try your second schematic directly?

Comment: Either schematic will probably work ;) Try it out on a breadboard first. And both of the schematics got Darlington :p - It was just a warning for the future ;)

Comment: So I did actually end up breadboarding it just now, and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. :)