# What is the chip used in CJMCU 0401 Capacitive Touch sensor?

Tags: capacitive

I'm trying to make my own PCB with touch keys. I've used the CJMCU 0401 capacitive touch sensor module and now I want to use it in my project. On the chip that is used in this module, there is only a code number 8224, I couldn't find any datasheet for this part number. Does anybody know where can I supply and find information about this IC?

Comment: [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321953/large-rectangular-touch-sensor/321958#321958) is another related question, I presume you will be able to solve it in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks Harry. I come up with using AT42qt1011 as it is a well-known chip.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a clone of the old Tontek TTP224.

Answer (score 1):

It's a no name, no known manufacturer chip that pushed out of a Chinese factory somewhere. You are unlikely to find it by itself, outside of Huaqiangbei, the Shenzhen, China electronics market place.

Instead of tracking down an obscure undocumented chip, try looking at the cap sense category in Digikey

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/capacitive-touch-sensors-proximity-sensor-ics/560

Comment: Thnaks for your help Passerby.