# Detecting human body current with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, detection, contact

I want to be able to detect on my raspberry when a human contact is made with a GPIO pin (or a cable linked to a pin).

I am pretty sure it's possible (for example when i see this kind of projects : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtDZ3fYyUN0, but they are not using a raspberry pi), but I am a real newbie in electronics and i can't figure out how this can be done...

Does anyone have some ideas? given that I have no experience at all with electronics...

Comment: *given that I have no experience at all with electronics.* So what are you prepared to do about that? What have you done to get the knowledge you need? What would be the need for all this? This site is not for "I have no clue but I want XYZ, show me how to do it" kind of questions.

Comment: It frustrates me how often I see questions like this. *I am a complete beginner but I want to detect this and sense that and do this and do that*. As a complete beginner, start **SIMPLE!** Start with an LED circuit, then start using transistor switches, then slowly build your knowledge like the rest of us. If you want to do programming, start by flashing an LED, then 2 or 3, then look at analogue and digital inputs/outputs and again, slowly build knowledge. **THAT** is the way to learn. Skipping the fundamentals is why you will run into a lot of issues when you get too ambitious early on.

Comment: Well, actually i obviously spent some time playing around with leds, buttons, i also managed to add 4 MCP23017, but it is still my first experience with electronics... And as a beginner I can't really determine what is simple and what is not... Also i was asking for some hints, not asking you to "show me how to do it".

Comment: *As a beginner I can't really determine what is simple and what is not*. Really? When I was a beginner, I learned that lighting LEDs at a voltage threshold using comparators was easy, but I knew that making my own fully automated drone was a bit beyond me. It's not too difficult. Why don't you look at the 'Electronics for dummies' book? I found that really useful when starting. It helped me with basics and simple circuit stuff. Build up a bit of knowledge, then come back to this. Took me 4 years to start designing a project I had in mind when I started. I had to build the knowledge first!

Comment: Here's [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/321953/8713) that is very similar to this one.

Comment: When i was a beginner and plugged up a mosfet switch, i accidentally invented a " human touch detection" circuit . Later on after gaining experience, I realised that It was ESD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a (capacitive) touch sensor for this. For example:  TTP223B.

Comment: Would that mean that the bareconductive board shown in the video has built-in touch sensors ?

Comment: It seems like that (although not obviously clear from the video itself).

Comment: Maybe more important, a piano without any 'feedback' plays really bad. Something with real switches (preferably checking the velocity, which you need more than a switch) is better. But a switch works already better than such capacitive sensors (at least for piano playing).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, i will give a try with AT42QT1070 sensor (since I need a lot of sensors) ! :)

Comment: I don't have experience with these kind of sensors. Btw, the IC you mentioned is a driver for sensor, not the sensor(s) itself.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to detect on my raspberry when a human contact is
>   made with a GPIO pin (or a cable linked to a pin).

And

> I am a real newbie in electronics and i can't figure out how this can
>   be done...

Touching pins is opening up a can of worms to ESD (electro static discharges) and potentially harming your electronics. I would suggest you start really simple by using one of these pushbuttons: -

[image]

Comment: Actually, I indeed was wondering if these "worms" couldn't be used to detect contact. So I guess the answer is "no", right ?

Comment: @AymericR. you need to properly define the objectives of what you want to achieve also. Touching a GPIO pin or detecting human body current is insufficient to get decent answers but yes, you do need to take care of ESD worms!

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the question title vs question detail might be a bit confused. As you say, you are a "real newbie in electronics", so that is understandable.

I think you are asking about "Detecting human body **contact** with raspberry pi".

In theory, detecting **contact** is doable. Detecting **body current** normally uses more electronics than contact.

As Andy aka explains, you'd need to solve problems caused by 'Electro Static Discharge' (ESD), which is likely to be unpredictable and variable. It can easily reach 1000's of volts, and destroy some of the electronics within the R-Pi.

A common way to detect human body *contact* is to detect changing capacitance caused by a human touching or being near a 'contact' connected to pins. The 'contact' can be insulated from actual contact with the human body which helps reduce some of the potential problems.

There are a bunch of ways to do this, many are covered by patents, which may inspire you, or prevent you applying the ideas. So you might try a patent search.

However, I'd suggest you start at the Arduino [Capacitive Sensing Library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense).

Essentially one output pin charges a tiny capacitor connected to a 'contact', and a second input pin monitors when the voltage has risen on the capacitor enough to flip the state of that second pin (ie reaches a consistent voltage level determined by the manufactured-in electrical behaviour of the sensing pin).

When a human approaches the 'contact' the capacitance changes and hence the time to charge the altered capacitance changes enough to reliably measure.

You might even start out by using an Arduino (maybe a small, cheap one like a Nano or micro), to detect the human contact. Then have the Arduino set an output pin high or low.

Connect the Arduino to the R-Pi. If the Arduino is running at 5V connect to the RPi via a voltage divider (two resistors, say 2k-ish and 3k-ish) to adapt to the R-Pi's 3.3V input. Or use an Arduino operating on 3.3V.

This way, if something (eg. ESD) wipes out the Arduino, the R-Pi is likely safe.

ESD is still an issue to resolve, but not quite as bad as a pin 'flopping around' connected to nothing, and Arduino input pins seem to be relatively robust.

EDIT:
I suggested using an Arduino because it'd be quick once you had the parts. It could be relatively cheap (Arduino clones are well under $3). Also, it'd protect the more expensive R-Pi, and it could do multiple button 'contacts'.

You could reduce the cost further by using a ATtiny85 digispark clone, with the Arduino Capacitive Sensing Library. I don't believe this is as robust as the ready made touch sensor module, but may give more opportunity to experiment and learn. For example, a DIY approach could allow for many different forms of 'contact'. (I'd probably buy a TTP223B module, and try this too, if I had time.)

However, you might even try the same approach as the Arduino Capacitive Sensing Library using 2 pins on your R-Pi. It'd need some high-ish value resistors, a small value capacitor and a robust way to measure the time it takes for an input pin to flip state.

I guess it might be possible to get robust precise timing for an R-Pi input pin change (maybe someone can point at a solution), but I don't know how (without disabling interrupts). IMHO this isn't a good fit for the R-Pi (R-Pi seems fine for precise output using the DMA controller). However YMMV.

Comment: You absolutely got it right, this is what I meant ! I have no Arduino at disposal but I can easily get the previously mentioned sensors, so I will play around with that. Thanks for the great clarification ! :)